# Linux Mint 9 On HP Mini 110 - External Monitor Stuck At Native Resolution Of Netbook Running @ 1024 X 600

Tags: resolution, linux-mint, display, hp-mini

As you'll have gathered from the title of my post I have a HP Mini 110 on which I have recently installed Linux Mint 9.

The native resolution of the netbook is 1024 X 600 and when I connect my external monitor to the netbook I am unable to increase the resolution beyond this to take advantage of the higher res available - the external monitor is capable of 1440 X 900.

All of the netbook's function keys are working except the one for switching between the internal and external display.

In mint's menu there is a "Monitors" section where I have also tried to change settings, again without success.

Any help and advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Edit \ Update 18-8-2010 - xrandr output as requested. Thanks for the reply, whitequark. Hopefully this will give you some clue as to how I might rectify the situation.
I've had some dealings with xorg.conf before, but don't really know my way around it.

```
the-thing@HP-Mini-110 ~ $ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 800 x 600, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA1 connected 800x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 255mm
   1440x900       59.9 +   75.0 
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0 
   1280x960       60.0 
   1152x864       75.0 
   1280x720       60.0 
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     66.0     60.0 
   832x624        74.6 
   800x600        72.2*    75.0     60.3     56.2 
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0 
   720x400        70.1 
LVDS1 connected 800x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 223mm x 125mm
   1024x600       60.0 +
   800x600        85.1     72.2*    75.0     60.3     56.2 
   640x480        85.0     72.8     75.0     59.9 
   720x400        85.0 
   640x400        85.1 
   640x350        85.1 
the-thing@HP-Mini-110 ~ $
```

Comment: Can you post output of `xrandr` ran in a terminal?

Comment: Are you sure your netbook can handle the Graphics suck?

Comment: The problem has been resolved - after grabbing updates and rebooting I am now able to bump up the resolution of the external monitor to 1440 X 900.

Thanks to both of you for the replies.